# Запуск файла от имени администратора

Tags: uac

Как через Win32API или C++ сделать так, что файл, который я создам, например `bat`, при запуске которого будут запрашиваться `Права администратора`. То есть создам файл, через `std::ostream::write` или через `WriteFile()` запишу туда все, что нужно и при этом мне нужно, чтобы был активен "Атрибут"( Если таковой существует для файла ), который будет запрашивать доступ к правам администратора при запуске файла. Раздела в реестре `Layers` у меня нет.